# Links in pluggable area to the root od web (visual studio connot resolve link)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pluggable

I use the pluggable framework shown here: [ASP.NET MVC - Pluggable application](http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.cz/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html) but I have problem with links (Visual Studio cannot resolve the link), images and css in module.  I have problem with link in area.

When I create action link within area this way:

`@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { Area = "" }, null)`

Visual Studio tells me that Action index and controller Home does not exist. The same with other link (images, css) which are placed on the root of project. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Horrible idea.  If it is not in the MVC books... don't do it!   I'm talking about that pluggable application link you referenced.  Areas that are excluded in a project ... I was just on a big enterprise application.  bin folder of main project with Areas would not clean correctly.  So in a project the controller methods I would update and debug... and it would not hit the symbols and the dll in bin of main did not match the code.

There is a huge problem with this hack.  Don't do pluggable areas.  I was searching for this as to why the architects went with this approach and I finally found an article and then based on the keyword searches I stumbled across other people complaining in the comments about how bad of an idea this was.

This has wasted and costed so much time and money for several teams on a large enterprise project.